# Is additional SQL syntax necessary to account for a field with a domain/coded values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, spatial-view

I'm attempting to create a spatial view.  The following statement returns an empty view, even though there are "Flushed" records in the MAINT_ACTIVITY field.

```
    SELECT h.OBJECTID, h.FACILITYID, h.SHAPE, r.Hydrant_ID, r.MAINT_ACTIVITY, r.MaintDate, r.GlobalID
    FROM wHydrant h
    JOIN wHydrant_Maint r
    ON h.FACILITYID = r.Hydrant_ID
    WHERE r.MAINT_ACTIVITY = 'Flushed'
```

If I remove the last WHERE clause, the query will return a view of all my hydrants.  If I change the WHERE clause to query another field, it will return correct results.  I'm only having issues with this specific MAINT_ACTIVITY field and the only major difference is that this field has a domain with coded values.  However, the coded values match the descriptions.  So, *Flushed* is the code and *Flushed* is the description.  Is additional syntax still necessary?  Why doesn't the above statement work?

*Update--When I query other fields in the Hydrant_Maint table, all the MAINT_ACTIVITY field results return as NULL, even though there are entries in the original table.

Comment: It's not totally clear from your post but if you have all NULLs in the wHydrantMaint columns after the join, this indicates a problem with your join. Are h.FACILITYID and r.Hydrant_ID both the same data type?

Comment: No, only the MAINT_ACTIVITY field results are null.  All other fields in the wHydrant_Maint table return the correct entries.  However to answer your question, yes, the join fields are both text types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL query in my question was actually correct.  Upon viewing the base table in SSMS, I saw that all the MAINT_ACTIVITY entries were indeed NULL.  Upon looking at the *Views* version of the table, I could see all my entries.  So, because the table was registered as versioned, I just needed to change the query to search the view table, not the base table.  The following returned the spatial view I was looking for:

```
SELECT h.OBJECTID, h.FACILITYID, h.SHAPE, r.Hydrant_ID, r.MAINT_ACTIVITY, 
r.MaintDate, r.GlobalID
FROM wHydrant h
JOIN wHydrant_Maint_evw r
ON h.FACILITYID = r.Hydrant_ID
WHERE (r.MaintDate >= '2014' AND r.MaintDate <= '2015') AND r.MAINT_ACTIVITY = 'Flushed'
```